# Best way to test functions defined in Main.hs?

Tags: haskell

I'm setting up some [Hspec](https://hspec.github.io/getting-started.html) test cases for my Haskell program. It looks like I import the functions I want, then write test functions for each one.

Although I have extracted some of my utility functions, I still have functions defined in `Main.hs`. When I write the test module(s), is it okay to do named imports directly from `Main.hs`?

Export from `Main.hs`:

```
module Main 
(main                                                                                                                                                                                                 
,awesomeFunction
)where
```

Import into `MyTests.hs`:

```
import Main

-- test for `awesomeFunction` goes here
```

It just doesn't feel like "best practice".

Comment: I don't see any problem with it. `Main` is a module, just one that the runtime looks for.

Answer (score 2):

In order to test functions, you need to put them inside your library, not executable. So in your `test-suite` you can depend on your library and test it. If you don't want to expose this function as a part of your public interface, you can introduce an [internal library](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#sublibs).

Similar questions:

- [How should I go about testing a monolithic executable package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51220260/how-should-i-go-about-testing-a-monolithic-executable-package/51220392#51220392)
- [Depend on test from bench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48227751/depend-on-test-from-bench)